# What does "404 (64)" mean?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, http-error

With Chrome's console open on [ncoa.org](http://www.ncoa.org), I saw the following two errors. Only the second of which is what I expect.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (64)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

[image: HTTP 404 errors on www.ncoa.org with the number 64 after them in Chrome's developer tools]

What I am wondering is: where did the `(64)` come from?

Note that this isn't reliably reproducible. It only seems to happen sometimes, but I've seen it elsewhere and managed to grab a screenshot there. I'm hoping this is something more interesting than a reference to a 64-bit process sneaking in or whatever.

Here are the missing resources:
http://www09.clicktale.net/i/7798.gif?r=0.335&UID=1299415204.1646124943&441321531
http://www.ncoa.org/assets/img/highslide/loader.white.gif

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "(64)" is returned by the web server in the 404 response for that request:

```
 % curl -v 'http://www09.clicktale.net/i/7798.gif?r=0.335&UID=798271705.1983171051&new&1053566178'
* About to connect() to www09.clicktale.net port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 75.125.82.68...
* Connected to www09.clicktale.net (75.125.82.68) port 80 (#0)
> GET /i/7798.gif?r=0.335&UID=798271705.1983171051&new&1053566178 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: www09.clicktale.net
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 64
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Fri, 18 Apr 2014 19:01:05 GMT
< Content-Length: 1245
<
< !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
...
```

Note the line that begins with `HTTP`.  More usually this would end with some text like `Not found` but in this case the server administrator has set it up differently.  You'd have to ask them what the significance of the "64" is.